# Symfony2 innerJoin is returning columns multiple time

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using `symfony2` for my application. for a query I'm using this:

```
$contents = $em->getRepository('BbdBongoAppBundle:Content')
        ->createQueryBuilder('c')
        ->select('c.id, c.title, c.sequence, c.sequence_count, c.category_sequence, c.unique_id, c.priority, c.status')
        ->addSelect('o.slug as owner')
        ->addSelect('cat.slug as category')
        ->addSelect('m.name as media')
        ->innerJoin('c.content_owner', 'o')
        ->innerJoin('c.category', 'cat')
        ->innerJoin('c.media', 'm')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
```

everything was before I added `->innerJoin('c.media', 'm')` because of it the content title and all other is returning twice if the media has two value, i.e (YouTube,Website) if media has one value its returning single result but if it has multiple it is returning multiple result.

What I want is single title with all media in a single result. i.e ( Titanic , YouTube, Web) now its returning (Titanic, YouTube, Titanic, Web)see titanic is twice.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks as though your Content entity has relationships with owner, category and media entities in which case why don't you retrieve Content entities (no inner joins) and traverse the media relationship (rather than using getArrayResult()). Would that be too inefficient?

Comment: i need getArrayResult because I'm using a bundle fro data table and it reads array result, i understand the your point with performance, but can you give me a sample code or clue?

Answer (score 0):

with this line you are not in object mode of doctrine.

```
->select('c.id, c.title, c.sequence, c.sequence_count, c.category_sequence, c.unique_id, c.priority, c.status')
```

By changing it to this code below, you will still have the object representation:

```
->select('c{id,title,sequence,sequence_count,category_sequence,unique_id,priority,status}')
```

[source](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html)